# Monthly to Daily Partitions in Oracle

Tags: oracle, partitioning

I have a table with monthly partitions on it. I was asked to change those monthly partitions to daily partitions. For that, can I do even if the data exists ? What prerequisites do I need to take care. I have never worked on partitions. Please help me. The existing partitions on the table are as

`PT_20190831_M,PT_20190930_M`, `PT_20191031_M` etc.

which has definition `TO_DATE(' 2019-08-31 23:59:59', 'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS', 'NLS_CALENDAR=GREGORIAN')`.

And these are Range partitions.

Answer (score 2):

Sure, it is called splitting a partition.

[Splitting a Partition of a Range-Partitioned Table](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/vldbg/maintenance-partition-tables-indexes.html#GUID-C27329F1-00C6-4952-A411-4B9A278E4DE8)

The below example (taken from the above URL) creates a table with quarterly partitions, then splits a quarter into monthly partitions:

```
CREATE TABLE orders
 (prod_id       NUMBER(6),
  cust_id       NUMBER,
  time_id       DATE,
  channel_id    CHAR(1),
  promo_id      NUMBER(6),
  quantity_sold NUMBER(3),
  amount_sold   NUMBER(10,2)
  ) 
  PARTITION BY RANGE (time_id)
  (PARTITION sales_q1_2016 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE('01-APR-2016','dd-MON-yyyy')),
   PARTITION sales_q2_2016 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE('01-JUL-2016','dd-MON-yyyy')),
   PARTITION sales_q3_2016 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE('01-OCT-2016','dd-MON-yyyy')),
   PARTITION sales_q4_2016 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE('01-JAN-2017','dd-MON-yyyy')) 
   );

ALTER TABLE orders 
  SPLIT PARTITION sales_q4_2016 INTO
  (PARTITION sales_oct_2016 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE('01-NOV-2016','dd-MON-yyyy')),
   PARTITION sales_nov_2016 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE('01-DEC-2016','dd-MON-yyyy')),
   PARTITION sales_dec_2016
   )
  ONLINE;
```

You can use the same concept for splitting monthly partitions to daily partitions.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed script. Will do in the same format. Thanks once again

Comment: Am getting the below Error when am trying to convert into daily partition -
ORA-14805: last resulting partition cannot contain bounds
14805. 00000 -  "last resulting partition cannot contain bounds"
*Cause:    An ALTER TABLE SPLIT PARTITION contained a description for the
           last partition which included the bounds.
*Action:   Do not specify bounds for the last resulting partition.